# Drupal 6 searching for "Authoring information"

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-6

I have been looking for a solution to this particular question and I haven't found a way to do it (if there is one).

I have content that is stored in a basic page content type. This content type has some authoring information: author and date.

If I do a search on 'Author Name' for example, there are no search results.

Any way to enable the search to look for these kind of information as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a view and expose the filter.  For instance, create a view and add a filter of `Node: user` and expose that filter so that people can search based on the user name.  The same can be done for the posting date.

For more on Views, take a look at its [documentation](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/views). Also these tutorials may be helpful:

- [Introduction to Views](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/12)
- [The power of Drupal Views](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/147)
- [How To: Using the Drupal Views module](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-tutorial)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this that doesn't require installing another module? I think is odd that you can search on custom added fields, but not search on default fields like author.

Comment: No, there is currently no way to do this with the Drupal core, though it is in discussion and being worked on for Drupal 8: http://drupal.org/node/233476